# I can't set a value to public variable

Tags: c#, variables

- I have a class that its name is `Cls_Options`.
- Inside this class I have the next variable:

  ```
  public bool JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus;
  ```
- I have (A) form contains a button.
- When clicking on this button I set a value for the variable `JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus`.

  ```
  private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Cls_Options.JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus = true;
      Close();
  }
  ```
- I show form (A) through form (B) and:
- I have an if statement to see what's the value of  `JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus`, If it was `true` then doing something and if `false` doing something else.

  ```
  MSGs.FrmMsgQuestion FrmMsgQuestion = new MSGs.FrmMsgQuestion();
  FrmMsgQuestion.lblMsg1.Text = Cls_Options.MsgSaveNew;
  FrmMsgQuestion.ShowDialog();

  if (Cls_Options.JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus== true)
  {

      int NewID = Cls_Countries.Joul_GetIDs();
      this.txt1.Text = NewID.ToString();

      this.txt2.Text = null;
      this.txt2.Select();
  }
  ```

my problem is: when I test the code I see that the variable in the next code saves the value that I assigned:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Cls_Options.JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus = true;
    Close();
}
```

but when I see value of the variable in if statement, I see that the variable has no value , it's keep its default value!!!
Help me, please

Comment: Where are you instantiating `Cls_Options`?

Comment: You should really show us how do you declare the _Cls_Options_ variable. I think that you declare it somewhere because you cannot use an instance property ( JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus) if you don't declare and initialize the class instance.

Comment: @Steve I declare it in the same form class. `namespace A_Project.PL
{
    public partial class FrmCountries_Op : Form
    {
        
        public string Type = "Normal";

       
        BL.Cls_Options Cls_Options = new BL.Cls_Options();`

Comment: So Cls_Options is the name of a variable of type Cls_Options (confusing isn't it?) At this point inside frmCountries_Op you have an instance with its values, in the other form you have a different instance and of course one instance doens't know the values of the other instance because the property is not static.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can set `Cls_Options` class property, if it is a public static class, that in your case it seems not to be the case.

```
public static class Cls_Options
{
   public static bool JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus = false;
}
```

then you can set the its value like:

```
Cls_Options.JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus  = true;
```

2.If `Cls_Options` is not static, then it must be a public class, and then you may set properties of an instance of the class like:

```
Cls_Options cls_o = new Cls_Options();
cls_o.JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

`public bool JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus;` defines an **instance** variable. There is a separate copy of this variable for each instance of the Cls_Options class.

You are trying to use this variable as a **static** variable. In this case there would be one copy of this variable (tied to the class not to an instance of the class).

To fix this you would do one of 2 things:

1. Make the variable static: `public static bool JoulVarQuestionMsgStatus;`
2. When you call it use an instance of the Cls_Options class that is created and stored somewhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if this was the problem he would be asking about a compiler error and not a runtime error.

Comment: @Brian Walker could you please explain more about? (When you call it use an instance of the Cls_Options class that is created and stored somewhere.)